# Facebook login with Firebase: error "auth/timeout"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting the error code "auth/timeout" (message: "The operation has timed out") after trying to login using Facebook Firebase provider with redirect flow. The error appears in `getRedirectResult.catch`. See the code below:

```
getRedirectResult(): void {
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()
        .then(result => {
            if (result.credential) {
                let token = result.credential.accessToken;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error on facebook login', error) );
}
```

I tried to login in desktop and iPhone SE and everything is OK. The problem occurs only in my iPad 2.

Comment: Can you provide details on iOS version, browser version and also make sure you are using the latest firebase version 3.4.

Comment: Sure, iOS 9.3.5, Safari latest version and Chrome 53.0.2785.109 and Firebase v3.3.2. So, I'll try to update Firebase and test it again.

Comment: @bojeil, I updated firebase to latest version and I still have the error. I happens in an Android phone too that I tested (don't know the model/versions)

Comment: I just reproduced the error in desktop Chrome by setting CPU throttling to 20x slowdown. So, the conclusion is that it occurs in slow end devices...

Comment: @Oswaldo it's an expected issue on slow networks, though it should not for slow devices - I haven't been able to reproduce with a CPU throttling 5x, and couldn't try higher. Have you been able to make your code work with another device on the same network?

Comment: @TMSCH yes, it worked in 2 iPhones SE and Mac, but not in iPad 2 and middle end Android device, all in same network. Try to reproduce in a 10 or 20x slower CPU

Comment: I guess the timeout occurs in Google Identity API

Comment: I am having the same issue: tablet/phones fail (about 20% of the time) to authenticate via firebase after the redirect with the auth/timeout error.
It never happens on laptops. I was able to reproduce it on a macbook with CPU throttling (20x), with full speed network. Oswaldo, Any progress on fixing/preventing the issue?

Comment: @Julien, I guess it was solved in newer Firebase API version, but Google still have a timeout, so throttling 20x I think it'll exceed limits